# What does CURLOPT_READFUNCTION do at a high level?

Tags: c, curl

I've read the docs at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html. And I understand that CURL will trigger the read_callback to do it's stuff.

At a high level though, because read_callback returns size_t, say for example x bytes, is the purpose of CURLOPT_READFUNCTION to tell the server, "hey, I'm about to send you x bytes". So the server knows exactly what to expect.

Is this the gist of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback's purpose is to pass in N bytes of data to libcurl for the transfer you've asked it to do. And to be able to do it piece by piece as the transfer progresses libcurl will call it over and over.

When libcurl is about to send data it will ask the application with this callback for the exact bytes to transfer. That's the entire purpose. It needs to return the amount of data so that libcurl knows how much data you copied to its bufffer.

The size of the total upload transfer, what the server is to expect, is usually set with a separate option, like `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` or `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE` depending on the particular request.